# Is there anything like predelete for the batch delete in sonata Admin bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm wondring if there are pre events in sonata Admins for example:
PreBatchDeleteAction() methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use for the batchDeleteAction this method:

```
public function batchActionDeleteIsRelevant(array $selectedIds, $allEntitiesSelected, Request $request = null)  
{
}
```

And the generale rule witch work with any batch action is:

```
batchAction<MyAction>IsRelevant(array $selectedIds, $allEntitiesSelected, Request $request = null)
{
}
```